# How can we impersonate the user running the browser in a Blazor dotnet core 3.1 app hosted on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis, blazor, impersonation

We are hosting a server side Blazor app on IIS. It's a web portal type app. The application pool running that app is running as a service account that has access to our API.

However, there are some parts of that API that need to be hit by individual users. It's the type of resource that users should have access to only their own resource, and not be able to view everyone else's. Hence why we need to access it via a user account and not the service account.

On the portal side (the blazor app) how can we impersonate the user that is actually running the browser? Right now this code 
`var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();`
just gets the service account running the app pool.

Comment: Why not have the Blazor server side app access the API using the service account on the user's behalf? Let the app itself handle authorization.

Comment: We were trying to keep the portal app as simple as possible, but we might have to go with something like that.

Comment: Impersonating users is not anywhere close to "as simple as possible"... especially if you ever need anything that is not a local resource on the box or if your users are not in Windows domain...

Comment: Well the way that we determine if a user has access to a certain resource is more complex than impersonating a user, so it's sort of the lesser of two evils.

Comment: If you enable windows authentication on an internal IIS server, with internal browser users, then you only need to return a `401` response to ask the browser for their windows credentials. (or block all anonymous access). And then `if (HttpContext.User.Identity is WindowsIdentity i){...}`.